# GemFire PDX Serialization not working with OQL in Pulse or with REST APIs?

Tags: spring, rest, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

We are using *Spring* as client to work with GemFire. Our data is getting saved to Regions of our running GemFire instances.

We are able to get data via *Spring* when we make get request.

Have done all configuration for Auto PDX serialization, However when we try to query data via OQL in Pulse or with GemFire REST Apis we get `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
{"message" : "Server has encountered while executing Adhoc query!", "stackTrace" : "com.gemstone.gemfire.rest.internal.web.exception.GemfireRestException: Server has encountered while executing Adhoc query! 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.rest.internal.web.controllers.QueryAccessController.runAdhocQuery(QueryAccessController.java:200) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) 
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:672)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:82)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:88) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: com.gemstone.gemfire.SerializationException: A ClassNotFoundException was thrown while trying to deserialize cached value. 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.EntryEventImpl.deserialize(EntryEventImpl.java:1561) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.EntryEventImpl.deserialize(EntryEventImpl.java:1546) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.VMCachedDeserializable.getDeserializedValue(VMCachedDeserializable.java:124) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.getDeserialized(LocalRegion.java:1275) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion$NonTXEntry.getValue(LocalRegion.java:9140) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.EntriesSet$EntriesIterator.moveNext(EntriesSet.java:183) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.EntriesSet$EntriesIterator.<init>(EntriesSet.java:121) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.EntriesSet.iterator(EntriesSet.java:85) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.ResultsCollectionWrapper.iterator(ResultsCollectionWrapper.java:181) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.QRegion.iterator(QRegion.java:225) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.CompiledSelect.doNestedIterations(CompiledSelect.java:712) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.CompiledSelect.doIterationEvaluate(CompiledSelect.java:577) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.CompiledSelect.evaluate(CompiledSelect.java:284) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.DefaultQuery.executeUsingContext(DefaultQuery.java:529) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.DefaultQuery.execute(DefaultQuery.java:365) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.DefaultQuery.execute(DefaultQuery.java:303) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.rest.internal.web.controllers.QueryAccessController.runAdhocQuery(QueryAccessController.java:180) 
... 40 more 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: in.cycorax.User 
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) 
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) 
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the query is trying to deserialize in.cycorax.User object, but that class is not present in the server's classpath.

What is your query? With PDX you should be able to query fields of your values without the objects needing to be deserialized on the server.

But if your query invokes a method on your object or tries to read a field that isn't part of the PDX serialized data (maybe even a misspelled field!), then gemfire will try to deserialize your object and see if it can invoke that method or find that field on the object.

So, you can either change your query so that it doesn't require deserialization, or you can add your classes to the server's classpath.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to what **Dan Smith** said above.  You must also be careful with "`SELECT * FROM /Region`" queries as well.  This query will attempt to deserialize the entire object.  As Dan mentioned, limit your queries to the fields of your object that will get serialized to PDX.  If your object gets deserialized in anyway, then you must have your application domain object types (classes) on the GemFire server's classpath, no exceptions.